# how to create in PHP analog of C# ' private const int ' and ' private const byte '?

Tags: c#, php, constants, byte, private

So in C# I create something like

```
    private const int HEADER_LENGTH = 13;
    private const byte SIGNATURE1 = 0x46;
```

How to create its analog in PHP?

Comment: Why should a constant be private? It's already save from manipulation by being a constant. I don't think it's necessary to hide it completely in any scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The closest things are:

```
const HEADER_LENGTH = 13;
```

which is not private and

```
private static $HEADER_LENGTH = 13;
```

which is not final. You cannot also constrict the type of the variable. There is also no 1-byte type in PHP – you should use an integer for that or a string with length 1.

You can implement something like that internally by overriding the `get_property_ptr_ptr` and `write_property` object handlers, but not with only PHP.

Comment: and will const SIGNATURE1 = 0x46; be avaliable for bites like operations? (see my next Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070298/what-is-php-for-c-readbytesstream-langth )

Comment: @Ole Jak Yes, you can do stuff like `999 & MyClass::SIGNATURE1`.